# Swift array init : data[section][row]

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, swift3

In Swift, I defined my var as:

```
var data : [[[String : Any]]] = [[[:]]]
```

then init it:

```
    for section in 0...1 {
        for row in 0...19 {
            let streamer = [
                "name" : "abcdef"
            ]
            data[section][row] = streamer
        }
    }
```

but I'm getting`fatal error: Index out of range.` for index `data[0][1]`, but there's not an error for index `data[0][0]`.

Do anybody know why I'm getting this error?

Comment: You're using raw, hardcoded indexes to try and access elements of your array. What did you expect to happen?

Comment: you could first check if `data[section][row]` exists (check if it is equal to nil) and only if it's **not** nil assign a value to it

Answer (score 1):

I see the problem, for some reason I was thinking swift would auto insert a section and row when I access them by subscript, but it seems that's not the case, so I changed my init to:

```
       for sectionIndex in 0...1 {
            var section : [[String : Any]] = [[:]]
            for rowIndex in 0...19 {
                let streamer = [
                    "name" : "abcdef"
                ]
                section.insert(streamer, at: rowIndex)
            }
            data.insert(section, at: sectionIndex)
        }
```

Comment: *some reason* is: Swift `Array` is value type rather than reference type.

Comment: @vadian Thank you, I completely forgot swift's Array is value.